# invalid UNC path with openrowset

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, unc, openrowset

I've created a folder called Public off the root of my C:\drive and have shared it with "Everyone".  I've also given NETWORK SERVICE read rights. But when I issue the following query in SQL Server 2008-R2, the error is that "\\FOO\public\my.csv" is not a valid path:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET (
  'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    'Text;Database=\\FOO\public\my.csv; ', 
    'SELECT * from my.csv'
    )
```

The 64-bit driver of ACE is installed. I'm on Windows 7 x64.  It's a 64-bit version of SQL Server.  My PC's machine name is "FOO".  It doesn't work with a simple `c:\public` path either.

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "'\FOO\public\my.csv' is not a valid path. Make sure
>   that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to
>   the server on which the file resides.".

I've configured the server so:

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE;
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE;
```

What else to check?  Thanks

Comment: If it was a 64bit/provider issue you'd get a provider error message, but you're not. The path you put in here is relative to your SQL Server installation, not your client. Are your server and client on the same machine?

Comment: I have tried putting the folder on the root of both the server and my development PC, and have tried this query from SSMS on both. Are built-in O/S identities like NT SERVICE included in "Everyone"?

Comment: what happens when you type `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'DIR \\FOO\public'`. Yuo can use this to 'see' what SQL Server sees. Also I notice in your error message there is only one backslash before FOO - is this a typo or is that the error message?

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestion. I'll try tomorrow morning at work. The single backslash before FOO in the error message was actually a Stackoverflow artefact. I had to edit it and put three backslashes in order for two of them to appear here.  \\\FOO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. The Database should point only to the folder and not include the file:

```
        'Text;Database=\\FOO\public; '
```